# kongchen swagger-maven-plugin - not known by Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jakarta-ee, swagger

I am trying to import in Eclipse a maven project.
Actually there's a root pom (root maven project) and several sub-projects.

One of the maven sub-projects seems to be using this maven plugin

https://github.com/kongchen/swagger-maven-plugin/

When I build the root project outside of Eclipse there are no issues.
I mean all sub-projects build fine.

But Eclipse itself does not seem to recognize this maven plugin.
So in Eclipse one of these sub-projects is always in red.

What can I do to make Eclipse recognize this maven plugin? Is there some particular Eclipse plugin which I need to install into Eclipse in order to fix this? Or... maybe there's something else I need to do?

The error which I see in Eclipse is below.

```
Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration:   

`com.github.kongchen:swagger-maven-plugin:3.1.4:generate`  

(execution: default, phase: compile)    

`pom.xml`   

Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem
```